# Поиск логов для пользователя по логину

Tags: php, codeigniter

Всем привет!

У меня есть таблица mysql, где хранятся логи о входе в аккаунт - login_history:

ID | Date | IP | Event | Username

**Вопрос:** как выводить конкретному пользователю логи, которые предназначены только для его логина (username)?

Проект на CI. Благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: `WHERE username = 'логин'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаете SQL запрос SELECT * FROM имя_таблицы WHERE username = логин_пользователя

после этого придет ответ со всеми данными логами по этому пользователю